# Snowflake organization account

Tags: database, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, rbac, cloud-storage, gcloud-compute

The questions are related to snowflake account with organization/ orgadmin role enabled.

1.Is it possible to detach a snowflake account from a snowflake
organization?

a. If yes, will the removed account become a standalone(separate contract)
account? How does the billing work?

b. Will the account url change after detachment?

c. Procedure to achieve the above?

2. In an organization, are the background services charged on each account?
3. Can we clone a database across accounts within an organization?
4. What happens to the other accounts within an organization when the
   primary account is deleted?
5. Can we get a cost comparison table between 2 standalone accounts and an
   organization with 2
   accounts?
6. After detachment can the account type/region/cloud provider be changed?

I have asked similar questions to snowflake support through support ticket system, But would like to get answers from the community too.

P.S If I get an answer from Snowflake, I will post it here!.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes - but you'd need to contact Snowflake support to do that.

a) not sure what you mean by standalone.  All accounts are technically standalone.  If you mean from a Snowflake contract, perspective, if you want them to be on a separate contract, you can do that.  If you don't, it can remain on the same contract.

b) see (a).

c) if you are using the URL that uses ORG and account name, then yes, the URL will change.  If you are using the URL that leverages an account locator and the deployment/region, then no.  If won't and can't change.

d) Call Support

1. background services are always related to an account.  An organization is just a way of grouping accounts.
2. No, but you can replicate data from one account to another account in Org.  Cloning can only ever be done within a single account.
3. What happens to what?  If this was related to cloning, then I don't think the question is valid.  A replication would cease to replicate.
4. No costs for Organization so costs are the same per credit and per TB costs that you'd see on any account.
5. No, you can't move an account around.  You'd need to create a new account, move your objects to the new account and then just remove your original account, if you wanted to move platform or region.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mike Walton, I have made some changes to the 3rd question. All of your answers were extremely helpful.

Comment: I don't think your changes on questions change the answers I gave.  Contracts with Snowflake are based on a fixed cost of credits and storage based on the edition that is purchased.  The cost for Organization functionality doesn't change that.